# Boost converter control in DCM

Tags: power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, control, boost

I am trying to find a reference where a boost converter is controlled in discontinuous conduction mode (DCM) with constant duty cycle and by changing the frequency of operation. More specifically, I wonder how the transfer function of the inductor current to the switching frequency can be derived.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Hey Andy, I thought the question was clear but apparently it wasn't... I was able to model a boost converter in CCM using circuit averaging. For DCM, the output voltage is a function of load, switching frequency and duty cycle (maybe even more things but I suppose those are the most interesting ones). I am looking for a method to derive the transfer function from inductor current to switching frequency but I have no clue on the methodology how to derive this...

Comment: I don't know if this might help you: [Calculator with formulas](http://www.stades.co.uk/Boost%20converter/Boost%20calculator.html).

Answer (score 0):

Page 24 of https://www.ti.com/seclit/ug/slyu036/slyu036.pdf Goes through DCM equations for Boost converters should help with deriving an inductor current transfer function